# How do you create a custom 404 page in Laravel 5.6?

Tags: http-status-code-404, laravel-5.6

I have not found any tutorials out there that address how to "properly" create a 404 page in this specific version of Laravel 5.6.  I found some outdated once that is a bit different that how Laravel 5.6 works.  Any inputs will help.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer by reading the Laravel Docs "Custom HTTP Error Pages".

Create a "Errors" Folder under "/resources/views/" and create a file named "404.blade.php" then add this code:

```html
@extends('../layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div id="login-container" class="container-fluid" style="background-color: lightgray;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 mt-1 mb-1 text-center">
                <h1>{{ $exception->getMessage() }}</h1>
                <a href="{{ asset('/') }}">back to home</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

then add this route to your "web.php" file:

```html
// 404 Route Handler
Route::any('{url_param}', function() {
    abort(404, '404 Error. Page not found!');
})->where('url_param', '.*');
```

I have written a blog about it: [click here](https://isparkcode.com/create-a-custom-404-page-in-laravel-5-6/)