# Http Exception Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6, httpexception

I have a problem with http exception. Actually, the 404 view I created does not appear. Only the default view appears (when i write in the url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/fr/sdfsdf`).

the view default is : 
[image]

My view displays an image, a title and the reason for the error, the path of view : `resources/views/errors/404.blade.php` :

```
@extends('layout')
@section('title',trans('errors.404'))
@section('body')
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="containe center_vertical_errors">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 text-center" >
                <h1 class="text-uppercase">{{trans('errors.404')}}</h1>
            </div>
           <div class="col-xs-12 logo-error">
               <img src="{{asset('image/logo.png')}}" alt="logo" width="300" height="300" title="logo" class="img-responsive img-centre-horizontal"/>
           </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 text-center reason-error" >
                <p class="text-uppercase">{{trans('errors.reason404')}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@stop
```

the code of Handler :

```
...
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
...
public function render($request, Exception $exception){

        if ($this->isHttpException($exception))
        {
            if($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException)
            {
                return response()->view('errors.404', [], 404);
            }
        }

        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
}
```

the code of route :

```
  Route::get('/', function () {return view('home/home');})->name('home');
    Route::get(trans('routes.news'),'PublicationController@index')->name('news');
    Route::post(trans('routes.news'),'PublicationController@index')->name('news');
    Route::get('/{slug}/{id}','PublicationController@show')->name('showNew');

    Route::get(trans('routes.team'), function () {
        return view('equipe/equipe');
    })->name('team');

    Route::get('lang/{language}', 'LanguageController@switchLang')->name('lang.switch');
 Route::put(trans('routes.changeDefaul'),'UtilisateurController@changeDefaul')->name('changeDefaul');
    Route::get(trans('routes.postNew'),'ActualiteController@create')->name('postNew');
    Route::post(trans('routes.postNew'),'ActualiteController@store')->name('postNew');

    Auth::routes();
    Route::get('/Utilisateur','UtilisateurController@index')->name('user');  
    Route::get(trans('routes.pdf'), 'PDFController@index')->name('pdf');
    Route::get(trans('routes.displayNew'),'ActualiteController@index')->name('displayNew');
    Route::put(trans('routes.displayOneNew'),'ActualiteController@get')->name('displayOneNew');
    Route::put('/actualite/suppressionActu','ActualiteController@delete')->name('actuSuppr');
    Route::put(trans('routes.updateActuality'),'ActualiteController@publier')->name('updateActuality');
    Route::post('actualite/update','ActualiteController@update')->name('updateNew');

    Route::get('/admin','AdminController@index')->name('adminIndex');
    Route::get('/fileManager','FileManagerController@index')->name('fileManager');
```

thanks to everyone for your help

> I did my research to find a solution, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: I think that yours "view folder" should be declared explict or did u mod it over app.php file? So Resources->view->errors to make it works

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo.

Comment: did u try to return view instead of return response()->view

Comment: You don't have to update the Exception handler, by default Laravel will load the `errors/404.blade.php` if there's one.

Comment: @JahStation, Yes, i tried. It doesn't change anything.

Comment: @ChinLeung. Yeah, I know, but  it doesn't work and I don't understand.

Comment: What is inside your view?

Comment: Possible answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51256791/3585500 (Which is use abort(404) instead of response().

Comment: When you say the default view appears, which one is it? Can you show us your route file too?

Comment: @ChinLeung.   I have made the changes

Comment: Okay you can do a `dd(get_class($exception));` in your Exception Handler because that is **not** a **404** for sure. Otherwise, you can look in your logs `storage/logs` to see what's going on.

Comment: The route is going into `Route::get('/{slug}/{id}','PublicationController@show')->name('showNew');`, that's why you are not getting the 404 view because it is not a 404.

Answer (score 0):

The actual path needs to be `resources/views/errors/404.blade.php`. Not sure if that is a typo on your side, but you missing the `views` directory.

Also for the default 5.6 behaviour you can keep the render function inside `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` as:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Comment: Do you have the same behaviour if the render function just returns the ```parent::render```

Comment: I have a different view: this page does not work (http error 500)

Comment: show your routes file, perhaps you have another route like ```/{foo}/{bar}```

Comment: In my route file I only have this route `Route::get('/{slug}/{id}','PublicationController@show')->name('showNew');` that has variables like `/{foo}/{bar}`.

Comment: then for your 404 to work you need to try another route like ```/testing``` or ```/one/two/three```. The problem for the ```500``` error is that you have a route that matches your example: ```/fr/sdfsdf```, so slug will be fr and id will be sdfsdf.

Comment: I add the file route